# How to print data in json that has 0 decimal point

Tags: php, json, curl, decode, jsondecoder

I have this Curl makeup

```
<?php
$url ="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=USD&tsyms=BTC";


$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
$json = json_decode($response);
echo $json->BTC;
curl_close($curl);
```

Trying to get the value of BTC, I got **1.659E-5** instead of **0.00001659**. Please I need help on how to decode this without this wrong figure.

Comment: Are you sure its not just that you get `"SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain"`

Comment: IF not please show us `echo $response;`

Comment: @RiggsFolly am running from localhost

Comment: I dont think that is relevant :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly **string(18) "{"BTC":0.00001662}"** This is what I got when I var_dump $response

Comment: It's not a "wrong" figure, it's just a different way of writing the same number

Comment: I think because the value is longer because others printed correctly...

Comment: @ADyson how can I reconvert it?

Comment: May be you can use `echo number_format($json->BTC, 8);`  for data representation (not for calculation) https://phpize.online/?phpses=79f4b18cdcbed2fa5d4f93ab1bea67ea&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP automatically uses scientific notation for smaaall numbers display.

You can use (s)printf() to control formatting :

```
// 8 decimals
printf('%.8f', $json->BTC); // 0.00001654
```